# createprocess: some applications run others do not

Tags: c++, winapi, createprocess

Help me understand problem in my code

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    STARTUPINFO si;
    ::ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);

    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ::ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    //TCHAR cmd[] = TEXT(R"("c:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe")");
    TCHAR cmd[] = TEXT(R"("c:\Program Files(x86)\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe")");
    BOOL res = ::CreateProcess(nullptr, cmd, nullptr, nullptr, FALSE, 0, nullptr, nullptr, &si, &pi);

    //iexplore - run ok, wmplayer - false & getlasterror = 2

    return 0;
}
```

What is my problem?

PS: Windows 10, Visual Studio 2017 CE, Platform toolset v141

Comment: On my windows machine, there is a space before "(x86)".

Comment: `2` = `FILE_NOT_FOUND`, double check the path you create.

Comment: forgive me. I am inattentive. Space between  Program Files and (x86)

Comment: You 'd better get the Program Files paths with the API.

Comment: Your problem is that your code neglects to check for errors.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Not so for raw string literals.

Comment: Don't hard code paths to system folders and system apps.  Use system APIs or the Registry to get the paths dynamically at runtime. In this case, you can use `SHGetFolderPath()` or `SHGetKnownFolderPath()` to get the correct `Program Files (x86)` path. Or use the `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\wmplayer.exe` Registry key to get the full path to `wmplayer.exe` itself.

Comment: @zett42 oh duh didn't notice that.

Answer (score 0):

> Don't hard code paths to system folders and system apps.(This may lead to errors on different machines / at different times, or spelling mistakes.)

@Remy Lebeau has metion that, you could use `SHGetFolderPath()` or `SHGetKnownFolderPath()` to get correct `Program Files` path. Or you could get the real path from registry.

Here's another simple way that we can get out of the hard code paths. `iexplore` and `wmplayer` are both the apps in windows. You could start it with "`start appname`" in command line(`cmd.exe`), Or use the code like below:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    STARTUPINFO si;
    ::ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);

    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ::ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    //TCHAR cmd[] = TEXT("cmd /c start iexplore");
    TCHAR cmd[] = TEXT("cmd /c start wmplayer");
    BOOL res = ::CreateProcess(NULL, cmd, nullptr, nullptr, FALSE, 0, nullptr, nullptr, &si, &pi);

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

Or you can use `ShellExecute/Ex` without starting `cmd` instead of `CreateProcess`:

```
ShellExecuteA(NULL,NULL, "wmplayer",NULL, NULL, SW_NORMAL);
```

Comment: Or you can use `ShellExecute/Ex()` instead and let it search the "App Paths" for you without having to use `cmd` at all. This is even stated as much in the `CreateProcess()` documentation